# check each record of a database table by a rest service

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, weblogic, eclipselink

i have a restful web service which must get each record of a table in the database and give it as input to another web service. the second web service is remote and its code is not accessible. then the remote service checks some conditions on that input and returns a boolean.

now i should update a column in that table based on the boolean returned. here it is:

```
@Path("/mobileCheck")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CheckMobiles {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;

    @GET
    public Response determineOwnership() {
        try {
            utx.begin();
            List<Object[]> list = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT u.national_code,u.usr_mobile from usr_mobile_verification u").getResultList();
            for (Object[] arr : list) {
                if (checkIdentityInfo(String.valueOf(arr[0]), String.valueOf(arr[1])))
                    em.createNativeQuery("update usr_mobile_verification m set m.is_owner='1' where m.national_code=?").setParameter(1, String.valueOf(arr[0])).executeUpdate();
                else
                    em.createNativeQuery("update usr_mobile_verification m set m.is_owner='0' where m.national_code=?").setParameter(1, String.valueOf(arr[0])).executeUpdate();
            }
            utx.commit();
            return ResponseHelper.ok("operation finished successfully!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseHelper.serverError();
        }


    private void checkIdentityInfo(String mobile, String nationalCode) throws MobileOwnershipException, RegistrationException {
        try {
            String url="some url";
            url = url.replace("NATIONALCODEPARAM", nationalCode)
                    .replace("MOBILEPARAM", mobile);
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

            WebTarget webResource = client.target(url);

            Response response = webResource
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .get();
            if (response.getStatus() != 204) 
                throw new MobileOwnershipException("failed");
            } catch (MobileOwnershipException e) {
            throw new MobileOwnershipException("failed");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RegistrationException(e);
        }
    }

    }
```

at the moment there are thousands of records in my table. soon it will increase to millions!

of course the above is not a good logic. this is what i know can be done. how can i improve my code. does using threads help? or i must avoid it? or any other optimization that can be done.

BTW i am using web logic, jakarta ee and eclips link and can't migrate to newer technologies.

--------UPDATE---------

i searched a lot and found some ways to improve such cases. as far as i learned we can use combination of async processing (i.e threads) and batch updates in these situations. this is what i ended up with:

```
        try {
            utx.begin();
            List<Object[]> list = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT u.usr_mobile,u.national_code from usr_mobile_verification u").getResultList();
            AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
            list.parallelStream().forEach(arr -> {
                try {
                    i.set(i.get() + 1);
                    if (isContactInfoValid(String.valueOf(arr[0]), String.valueOf(arr[1])))
                        em.createNativeQuery("update usr_mobile_verification m set m.is_owner='1' where m.national_code=?").setParameter(1, String.valueOf(arr[1])).executeUpdate();
                    else
                        em.createNativeQuery("update usr_mobile_verification m set m.is_owner='0' where m.national_code=?").setParameter(1, String.valueOf(arr[1])).executeUpdate();
                    if ((i.get() % 30) == 0) {
                        em.flush();
                        em.clear();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
     
            utx.commit();
            return ResponseHelper.ok("operation finished successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseHelper.serverError();
        }
```

i think use of parallel stream and batch update is good but it is not enough. it doesn't reduce time much. i'm dealing with nearly 100 million data. what else should i do?

Comment: You need to read in the data in pages, and deal with each page in its own transaction to get the full use of parallelism. Each page read should go to its own process to start a transaction iterate isContactInfoValid on each value and update them within the transaction. You can then tweak the size of each page/batch handled per thread to optimize DB and transactional resources to the number of calls to isContactInfoValid being made. Should simply be a matter of using setFirstResult(), setMaxResults() with ordering if you use JPQL instead of a native query for fetching the data.

Comment: i don't understand why paging would help! this service doesn't have a ui. so how to go to other page? even if there is a ui changing pages would take too much time. can u show me by code?

Comment: Paging is just a concept used to fetch limits amount of data at a time that you can then pass to some other process to handle. If you want to load the full list of values from the full table in one query all in memory, go for it, but you should break it up into batches for multiple processes to handle in parallel. Say 100 values per process. Using pages though would allow you to have some other process load a page of what ever entity backs the usr_mobile_verification table and just return if there might be more, allowing the main method to create another for the next page.

Comment: The process spawned would then have these entities in memory and can batch the isOwner update statements into a single update statement for the page, all as one transaction independent from the other pages being handled.

Answer (score 1):

First, Eclipse Link as JPA provider and WebLogic as Jakarta EE implementation are quite modern and powerful.

Second, there are no miracles in this world: if you need to check all records one-by-one across third party service, you will be treated to do this.

Third, you do not need to manage transactions yourself, WebLogic is smart enough to do this for you: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/transactions.html#BNCIH

Fourth, why do you trigger this long term operation syncroneously by REST? May be it will be usefull to do this asynchroneously?

Jakarta EE provides various ways to do that.

1. You may invoke REST, even servlets, asyncroneously: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/servlets012.html#BEIGCFDF
2. You may inject Session bean and annotate any business method as @Asynchronous: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/ejb-async.html#GKIDZ
3. You may schedule your operation any way you need using Enterprise Timer Service: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/ejb-basicexamples005.html#BNBOY
4. You may fire up async CDI Events: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/cdi-adv005.html#GKHIC
5. You may batch a job: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/batch-processing.html#GKJIQ6
6. You may use Message-Driving beans https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/ejb-intro003.html#GIPKO

Finally, is it actually needed to refer third party service? Would it be better to implement the logic yourself?

Comment: there is no way not to use third party service. that's why! i will soon update my code and add the optimization to it to see if my solution is true or not. thanks!